# How to update DB records using a dynamically generated link

Tags: mysql, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a requirement to generate an email to administrator whenever a user sign up. Administrator will approve the registration by clicking on a link provided in email and database should get updated, without admin to login to administrator console.

I am looking for best practice to code this scenario with keeping application security intact. I can generate email with dynamic rendom value attached to the link(provided in email) URL, but i am not sure how to keep a track of this on application side?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try having java instance an XML connection to a SSS (server side script) such as PHP to generate a code and save it to database. Your PHP can also email it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a random validation number when the user signs up, and store it in the database with the user record. Then generate an email with a link such as

```
http://foo.bar.com/approveUser.action?userId=<theUserId>&validationToken=<theRandomNumber>
```

When the `approveUser` action is invoked, check if the validation token stored in the database for the given user ID matches with the token sent as parameter, and if so, approve the user.

Comment: hummmm.....that's what i was thinking of, thanks all for your valuables comments.